# NHibernate logging using NLog.Web.AspNetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, nhibernate, nlog

I've wasted almost a whole day trying to make NHibernate log messages via NLog.Web.AspNetCore for an ASP.Net Core project – to no avail. The only example I could find is hidden [deep inside the NHibernate Git repository](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/5.1.2/src/NHibernate.Example.Web/Infrastructure), but it doesn't work with modern versions of the Microsoft logging libraries. Not to mention it's a really skectchy solution, given that I'd have to copy/paste the two auxiliary classes in that folder to manually bridge the loggers and logger factories between the Microsoft world and the NHibernate world.

Is there any sane, modern, elegant solution (or NuGet package) I didn't manage to identify? I feel I'm missing something simple here, but for the life of me, I don't seem able to make it work.

For clarity, I'm looking for a way to pipe NHibernate's own log messages through NLog, **not** to persist NLog's messages to a database using NHibernate.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by `NHibernate logging` ? Does it mean that you want to log all executed SQL-statements? Found these articles: https://gunnarpeipman.com/nhibernate-log-sql-debug-window/ and https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-nhibernate-log-sql/ (Suggesting that one inherits from EmptyInterceptor and hooks into sessionFactory)

Comment: @RomanArtiukhin, NHibernateToMicrosoftLoggerFactory is one of the two copy/paste, incompatible, sketchy classes I mentioned in the OP (notice it's declared in the folder at the URL – it's a hack, not part of the framework).

Comment: @RolfKristensen that's an interesting approach – and I hadn't found those articles. It's certainly a solution which works, but it's still sketchy – you end up capturing only SQL, not other internal NHibernate messages and warnings; also, it assumes your code will inject the interceptor in all sessions in the application (I have at least one stateless and one stateful session in various parts of the code). I still hope I'll find a way to use NHibernate's native `NHibernateLogger.SetLoggersFactory()`, and just let NHibernate do its thing from then on...

Comment: `incompatible, sketchy classes` Can you elaborate more on incompatible? What exactly is incompatible? `NHibernateToMicrosoftLogger` is trivial adaptor class. If `ILogger` interface has changed just adjust it - it shouldn't be too complex.

Comment: @RomanArtiukhin, I have multiple issues with that approach, and this is an inadequate medium to express them all. The point of libraries and package managers is specifically to ensure things are orchestrated smoothly when transitioning from one version to another of any library in the ecosystem – it shouldn't be my responsibility to create and maintain bridges between major components (e.g. the ORM and the logging infrastructure). For instance, the Github library uses Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 2.0.0.0, but the current NuGet version is 3.1.8; there are multiple breaking changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several months later (!), I finally got fed up with rolling my own micro-library for each and every project, and decided to write a public library instead: [RBC.NHibernate.NLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RBC.NHibernate.NLog/).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this (Works only from NHibernate > 5.1.0):

```
NHibernateLogger.SetLoggersFactory(new NHibernate.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactory());
```

And implement NLogLoggerFactory like this:

```cs
using NHibernate;
using NLog;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NHibernate.Logging.NLog
{

    public class NLogLoggerFactory : INHibernateLoggerFactory
    {
        private readonly LogFactory _factory;

        public NLogLoggerFactory(LogFactory logFactory = null)
        {
            _factory = logFactory ?? LogManager.LogFactory;
        }

        public INHibernateLogger LoggerFor(string keyName)
        {
            return new NLogLogger(_factory.GetLogger(keyName));
        }

        public INHibernateLogger LoggerFor(Type type)
        {
            return new NLogLogger(_factory.GetLogger(type.ToString()));
        }
    }

    class NLogLogger : INHibernateLogger
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        private readonly Dictionary<NHibernateLogLevel, LogLevel> LevelMapping = new Dictionary<NHibernateLogLevel, LogLevel>() {
            { NHibernateLogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Trace },
            { NHibernateLogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Debug },
            { NHibernateLogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Info },
            { NHibernateLogLevel.Warn, LogLevel.Warn },
            { NHibernateLogLevel.Error, LogLevel.Error },
            { NHibernateLogLevel.Fatal, LogLevel.Fatal },
            { NHibernateLogLevel.None, LogLevel.Off },
        };

        public NLogLogger(NLog.ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }

        public bool IsEnabled(NHibernateLogLevel logLevel)
        {
            return _logger.IsEnabled(LevelMapping[logLevel]);
        }

        public void Log(NHibernateLogLevel logLevel, NHibernateLogValues state, Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Log(LevelMapping[logLevel], exception, state.Format, state.Args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to make a couple of minor syntactic changes for it to compile, and I'm still not happy with the NHibernate team for not providing a compatible middleware out of the box – but it works! And since this is the first time something actually, finally works, you have my thanks!

Comment: Happy that it works. You are very welcome to update my answer, and correct any syntax-errors. I have not compiled the code myself, but just wrote it from interfaces.

Comment: Done. I chose to exclude your failsafe switch block, and used a dictionary instead. I did that for two reasons: (1) speed, and (2) I actually want to know if anything breaks in the future (i.e. if NHibernate adds a new log level that doesn't match the existing ones), instead of silently hiding the mismatched messages. If I have time, I'll actually create a pull request with this on the main NHibernate repo – unless you want to do that.

Thank you again!